# CLOB decoding after changing language

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle database were moved from 11i to R12 with another language.

- Old language `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252`
- New language `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

When I try to read something from fields with CLOB data type, wrong characters are read.
I tried to use `CONVERT` and `UTL_RAW.CONVERT`, but it didn't help.

I use PL/SQL to connect to DB.

Comment: Problems only occur with `CLOB` fields? Are `VARCHAR` fields concerned too?

Comment: I found problem only with `CLOB`, `VARCHAR` displays correctly.

Comment: How was the database migrated? Did you get warnings on export/import? Please provide an example of a problem. Use the `DUMP` function on a single character to make sure of the character set.

Comment: for example text `111` in HEX format looks like `313131` for `WE8MSWIN1252`
but for `AL32UTF8` it is `3100 3100 3100`

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `NLS_LANG` environment variable is `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` on both client and server machines.

Comment: Language on client is `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` now. I changed it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` but it didn't help. Also I need to use `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` on the client machine to connect to old DB also.

Answer (score 0):

try function convert
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm

I am using it for conversation varchar2 fields but in documentation write that it allow convert blob and clob

CONVERT(:field, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'UTF8')

good luck